# Withdraw a staked token from Smart contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, binance-smart-chain

I staked some tokens in the below contract address. The website is down now. I tried to unstake the tokens from the contract. The written contract in the code doesn't show me the withdraw function in web3 connected BSC.

This is the contract address.

```
https://bscscan.com/address/0x56f8b3ef32f822684d0c1d24c9260de9654932b3#code
```

I want to call the below function in that smart contract. Is there a way to do it?

```
Function: withdraw(uint256 _pid, uint256 _amount) ***
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The main contract for this address is `MasterChef` *(t e r)* but the `withdraw()` function is in the `MastorChef` *(t o r)* contract.

External callers can only invoke `public` and `external` methods of the main contract.

And since this function is not in the main contract (and is not a dependency of any of the main contract functions), the function is unreachable and not possible to execute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: would you suggest any other way to withdraw the token ?

Comment: I just found an older version of the website in waybackmachine. https://web.archive.org/web/20211028131416/https://marbles.finance/
I could see the code for withdrawable balance (useWithdrawableBalance) and withdraw (const unstake()) in  https://web.archive.org/web/20211028131416js_/https://marbles.finance/static/js/main.chunk.js. Could it be used?

Comment: This is how they got the master chef contract address
 const masterChefContract = Object(_sushi_utils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["getMasterChefContract"])(sushi);

Comment: I have around 5k USD profit in that contract. I wish to set a bounty of 1k USD for anyone who can help to resolve this issue.